# Excel button click event in Python

Tags: python, excel, com, pywin32

I was using pywin32 to make a connection between Python and Excel and I was starting to deal with events. It happens that in the project I'm working with, I would need to capture a button click event in Python. I've seen events from Workbooks and Worksheets, but I can't figure out the click ones.

```
class WorkbookEvents:

    def OnSheetSelectionChange(self, *args):
        #print(args)
        print("You changed the selection")
        #print(args[1].Address)
        #args[0].Range("A1").Value = "Range :" + str(args[1].Address)

workbook_events= WIN32.WithEvents(wb, WorkbookEvents)
```

Answer (score 0):

quite late for an answer but I got it working with this piece of code (and using the ActiveX "Command Button" control in Excel)

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pythoncom    
import sys
import time

#The event handlers container
class wsEvents:
    def OnClick(self,*args):
        print('Button Clicked')


xlApp = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks("Book1.xlsm")
ws=xlwb.Sheets("Sheet1")
xl_events=win32.WithEvents(ws.OLEObjects("CommandButton1").Object,wsEvents)

# define initalizer
keepOpen = True

while keepOpen:

    time.sleep(0.1)
    # display the message
    pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()

    try:

        # if the workbook count does not equal zero we can assume Excel is open
        if xlApp.Workbooks.Count != 0:
            keepOpen = True

        # otherwise close the application and exit the script
        else:
            keepOpen = False
            xlApp = None 
            sys.exit()

    except:
        # if there is an error close excel and exit the script
        keepOpen = False
        xl = None
```

The ActiveX command button is loaded in Excel as an "independent" COM(OLE) object that is referenced by the worksheet where it is displayed. The Excel API permit to get a reference to OLE objects as [explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.oleobject.object) and easily done in python code.

Basically the event handlers are not managed by the worksheet but by the Command Button object instead, and of course the events supported by a Command Button are OnClick etc...Turns out that the solution is elegant and that win32com has much respect for COM :)

Credits must be given to [Alex Reed blog](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-excel-events-python-alex-reed) about his snippet to keep python script waiting for new events.