# Python Xlwings - Best way to reading data continuously from excel Sheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, xlwings

I am developing one application in python using MS Excel as my frontend for python. Where I need to read excel cells every time to check if the value is update by user. After Update there is some logic to be called to Pull data from DB and put it to Next cell.

[Input as my search field and output as a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw6tj.png)

I am using following Logic but its consuming a lot of resources and making life difficult if using cursor to move from one cell to another.

```
sht = self.wb.sheets[0]
while True:
    search_id = sht.range('C10').value
    search_result = search_for_id(search_id)
    sht.range("C12").value = search_result
    time.sleep(1)
```

My excel is getting stuck every time i use. I can increase delay but it will affect my performance. I need this to work on live basis. without even a single second of delay will cost much.

**Note: I am working on fintech project. for ease of understanding made my scenario very simple**

Comment: Excel has VBA callbacks when any cell changes.  Surely that would be a better signal for you to trigger your check.  If the sheet hasn't changed, no point in wasting time checking.

Comment: You should handle Events (rather than constantly polling).  Eg [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63336153/445425)